# iOS Table View: How to update a label in every table view cell (after didUpdateLocation was fired)

Tags: ios, uitableview, cllocation

I want to update the remaining distance of some stored locations (every table view cell is a location) to the current position. So after the current position is changed (didUpdateLocation is called), I want to update every label containing the remaining distance in my table view. reloadTable works, but is not what I want since selected cells get deselected and everything is reloaded. I just want to refresh this one label. What is the best and most performant way to do this? Registering for updates within the tableview cells?

Comment: Is there a performance penalty for reloading your table? Assuming there isn't, I would reload it. Try keeping track of selected cells and reselect them after reloading.

Comment: If you need to update the only label just add new weak property of type UILabel to your viewController class, associate it with the selected cell and update text after didUpdateLocation call.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the visible cells with…

`[self.tableView visibleCells]`

…get there indexes with…

`[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]`

…and refresh just these cells with…

`[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray 
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]`